# Postfix tls errors with gmail as relayhost

Tags: centos, postfix

while configuring a php contact form ive run into a bizarre issue where postfix refuses to send an email, I've narrowed the errors down to one and occasionally a second which.

The first is :

from /var/log/maillog

```
 connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c03::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
Jun 11 16:57:59 site postfix/smtp[1315]: E79467A7: to=<apache@site.[domain].com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109]:587, delay=0.19, delays=0.01/0/0.16/0.02, dsn=5.5.1, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109] said: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y131-v6sm20355089qka.30 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

Allow less secure apps is enabled as recommended in the error log, and I've added tls support in main.cf

dump of main.cf

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
command_directory = /usr/sbin
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix
#myhostname = [site].[domain].com
#mydomain = [domain].com
myorigin = $mydomain
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
#mynetworks = <192.168.122.0/24, 192.168.100.0/24, 127.0.0.0/8>
relayhost = [smtp.gmail.com]:587
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases


debug_peer_level = 2
debugger_command =
         PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
         ddd $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.10.1/README_FILES
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_tls_policy_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/tls_policy
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/pki/tls/cert.pem
```

I'm not familiar with postfix, how it works, or what it requires.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Good answers that will probably get you on the right track. But here’s a little help that might go a long way to explain this authentication issue: http://postfix.state-of-mind.de/patrick.koetter/smtpauth/smtp_auth_mailservers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### As for the first message:

```
connect to smtp.gmail.com[2607:f8b0:400d:c03::6c]:587: Network is unreachable
```

This means that the network configuration of your server doesn't allow postfix to reach an IPv6 address, but that you configured postfix to try and use IPv6.

You should check your host configuration and eventually if you don't have access to an IPv6 network, disable ipv6 processing in postfix:

```
postconf -e inet_protocols=ipv4
```

### As for the second:

```
Jun 11 16:57:59 site postfix/smtp[1315]: E79467A7: to=<apache@site.[domain].com>, relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109]:587, delay=0.19, delays=0.01/0/0.16/0.02, dsn=5.5.1, status=bounced (host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109] said: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y131-v6sm20355089qka.30 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command))
```

The message can be read like this:

- `relay=smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109]:587, delay=0.19, delays=0.01/0/0.16/0.02`

  - Postfix sent the mail to the relay host specified
- `dsn=5.5.1, status=bounced`

  - The host refused to handle the message
- `host smtp.gmail.com[173.194.205.109] said: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at 530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError y131-v6sm20355089qka.30 - gsmtp (in reply to MAIL FROM command)`

  - This is an explaination sent by the relayhost you use for the rejection. In this case it's google way of saying that you didn't send an login/password to authenticate on the relay, or that the login/password used is incorrect.

To explain/help you further the content of `/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` and `/etc/postfix/tls_policy` would be useful.

`/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd` should contain a line like that

```
smtp.gmail.com <gmail-accound-username>:<gmail-password>
```

Comment: Oh, Looks like i was an idiot and used smtp.google.com for some friggin reason instead...

Comment: `postconf -e ...` so elegant! :+1:

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding the first error** I do agree with silmaril.

You've enabled IPv6 for postfix but v6 networking is not configured on your system, or a firewall is blocking v6 connections to `smtp.gmail.com`.

**Regarding the second issue** I guess you probably missed to run the following while configuring postfix for using Gmail SMTP as relay:

```
sudo postmap /etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
```